# AWS S3 Java SDK not copying file to folder

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Java 8 here. I have an S3 bucket (`myapp-bucket`) with the following folder substructure:

```
/artwork
    /upload
    /staging
```

Here's what the `myapp-bucket/artwork` folder looks like:

[image]

I have software that uploads image files to the `/upload` folder, and then another app that I'm writing is supposed to process that image and copy it over to the `/staging` folder. The code I have to perform this S3 copy is as follows:

```
CopyObjectRequest copyObjectRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(
  bucketName,
  objectKey,
  destinationBucket,
  destinationKey
);

log.info(
  "copying object from s3://{}/{} to s3://{}/{}",
  bucketName,
  objectKey,
  destinationBucket,
  destinationKey
);

// Constructed via 
AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).build();
amazonS3.copyObject(copyObjectRequest);
```

When this runs, I see the following log output I see is:

```
[main] DEBUG com.me.myapp.ImageProcessor - copying object from s3://myapp-bucket/artwork/upload/rlj_amp244001_270.jpeg to s3://myapp-bucket/artwork/staging
```

But the final state of the `myapp-bucket/artwork` folder looks like this:

[image]

So it looks like, instead of copying `myapp-bucket/artwork/upload/<theImageFile>` to the `myapp-bucket/artwork/staging/` directory, its creating a new *file* directly under `/artwork` and naming it `staging`, and likely copying the binary contents of the image into that staging file. Where am I going awry?! I just want to end up with `myapp-bucket/artwork/staging/<theImageFile>` -- thanks in advance!

Comment: Typo - you didn't end the S3 bucket folder name with a `/`.  Bear in mind that S3 did exactly what you told it to - it took your jpeg and put it at `s3://myapp-bucket/artwork/staging`, but that is its own file and not a folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

S3 doesn't have folders/directories - it's just sugar over a flat storage. So your `destinationKey` should look like `artwork/staging/rlj_amp244001_270.jpeg`